# Angular 2 nested routing: view or url not being updated

Tags: angular, router

Main router:

```
@RouteConfig([
    { path: '/', name: 'Intro', component: IntroComponent, useAsDefault: true },
    { path: '/locator/...', name: 'Locator', component: LocatorComponent },
])
```

Child router:

```
@RouteConfig([
    { path: '/bydistrict', name: 'ByDistrict', component: ByDistrictComponent },
    { path: '/bycounty', name: 'ByCounty', component: ByCountyComponent },
    { path: '/byregion', name: 'ByRegion', component: ByRegionComponent, useAsDefault: true }
```

Main nav:

```
    <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#" [routerLink]="['Locator', 'ByDistrict']">Search</a>
    <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#" [routerLink]="['Locator', 'ByCounty']">Counties</a>
    <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#" [routerLink]="['Locator', 'ByRegion']">Regions</a>
```

**ISSUE #1:** When clicking through the main nav links, the view is always updated correctly but the URL never updates to reflect the first nav item "Search" when it is selected. It always remains set to the previously active path. The other two update correctly.

**ISSUE #2:** When navigating to a new route from a child component (e.g. ByDistrictComponent), the URL is updated to reflect the new route, but the view does not get updated. This problem occurs regardless of whether using `[routerLink]="['/Locator', 'ByCounty']` is used or from code via `this._router.navigate(...)`.

For both scenarios no error is reported in the console.

I just updated today to the current version of Angular 2 (2.0.0-beta.11) and it's dependencies. The problem also existed in the previous release I was using (beta.9).

I'm posting both issues as a single question because I think they may be both connected to an unexpected behavior when using child routers.

### UPDATE #1

Both issues only start occurring when Router is injected into the constructor of a component that is loaded via a directive from the ByDistrictComponent (referenced in the child routes).

```
import { Component, OnInit }            from 'angular2/core';
import { ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, ROUTER_PROVIDERS, Router } from 'angular2/router';

@Component({
    ...
})
export class DistrictListComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor(
        private _router: Router) { // <-- causes both issues
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: you should show us `main.ts` and `child.ts` because everything works in my case with `beta-11`. and show your `bootstrap function`.

Comment: or can you just come up with plunk?

Comment: In trying to create a simplified repro, I found specifically what triggers both issues. I have edited the question with additional details under the heading UPDATE #1. I'm now trying to figure out how to create a plunk from local files.

Comment: I added all the code to plunker (http://plnkr.co/edit/mlnHkb?p=preview). I had to change the angular 2 beta version  to .9 because .10 isn't on the CDN yet. Getting a 404 plunker-specific error in the console though, so this isn't runnable. However, you can see the entire code base that I am using on my local machine to reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Working Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/OejwHS?p=preview)

Note :

1) I have changed `index.html` page.
2) changed `main.ts`

`main.ts`

```
import {Component,bind} from 'angular2/core';
import {bootstrap} from 'angular2/platform/browser';
import {Router,ROUTER_PROVIDERS,RouteConfig, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES,APP_BASE_HREF,LocationStrategy,RouteParams,ROUTER_BINDINGS} from 'angular2/router';
import {App} from './app';

bootstrap(App, [
      ROUTER_PROVIDERS,bind(APP_BASE_HREF).toValue(location.pathname)
      //provide(LocationStrategy,{useClass: HashLocationStrategy} you can also use this if you don't want to you bind().
    ])
  .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

Comment: `bind(APP_BASE_HREF).toValue(location.pathname)` is quite outdated. This should be `provide(APP_BASE_HREF, {useValue: location.pathname})`

Comment: Thanks I was just updating the answer and got your quick comment. Btw thanks i have already updated with comment.

Comment: Thank you for getting the plunker working. Curiously, neither of the issues I reported are occurring. I traced the difference to you having commented out the ROUTER_PROVIDERS assignment in app.ts. If I un-comment this, then both of my issues are reproduced. I understand that it is not needed, but surprised at the havoc its inclusion causes.